# Delete last letter of a string of numbers

Tags: javascript, string, types, int

I'm trying to make a calculator. The code inside the Plus functions work correctly and concatenates the string. Pressing these two buttons below...

```
document.getElementById('Textbox').innerHTML += '5';
document.getElementById('Textbox').innerHTML += '9';
```

Results in the intended 59 being printed to screen.

I want to go back to 5, deleting the 9, so the Calculator's CE button. But this code below makes the number on screen 58. How do I force JS to see this as a string type?

```
document.getElementById('Textbox').innerHTML--;
```

Comment: It's a string.  You have to treat it like a string.  Use [`substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), not arithmetic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that use substring method

```
var a = "59";
a = a.substring(0, a.length - 1);
console.log(a);
result: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I would call [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on innerHtml to cast it to an array of characters. I would then use the [pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) method to remove the last character. And then use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to create a string that you can assign to innerHtml.

```js
const textBoxElement = document.getElementById('Textbox');

// create an array of characters
const innerHtml = textBoxElement.innerHTML.split('');
  
// remove the last character
innerHtml.pop();

// create and assign a string
textBoxElement.innerHtml = innerHtml.join('');
```

Comment: Or, you could just use `substring(int,int)`.